# Passing parameters to ode 45 in MATLAB

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I have to solve the ODE ,
 [image]

where $f\epsilon$ is noise which is generated by random number.

My question is how can I pass the variables $\beta,\gamma,\mu,noise,N$ as inputs to `ode45`.

My code is

```
function [T,X,Y]=Stochastic_Solve(x0,y0,MaxTime,Step,noise,mu,beta,gamma,N)
    t=0;
    X=x0;Y=y0;T=[0];
    while(t<MaxTime & X>0 & Y>0)
        random_noise=randn(1);
        noise=noise*random_noise/sqrt(Step);  
        [tt,p]=ode45(@Equations,[t t+step],[X,Y],mu,beta,gamma,noise,N);

    end  

 function eqns=Equations(t,y,mu,beta,gamma,noise,N)
       eqns=zeros(2,1);
       eqns(1)=mu*N-((beta*y(1)*y(2)/N)+noise)-mu*y(1);
       eqns(2)=((beta*y(1)*y(2)/N)+noise)-gamma*y(2)-mu*y(2);
```

I get errors as

```
Error in observationalNoise>Equations (line 32)
       eqns(1)=mu*N-((beta*y(1)*y(2)/N)+noise)-mu*y(1);   


Error in odearguments (line 90)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 115)
    odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options, varargin);

Error in observationalNoise>Stochastic_Solve (line 25)
        [t,p]=ode45(@Equations,[t t+step],[X,Y],mu,beta,gamma,noise,N);
```

So,when calling `ode45` how can I give the parameters that are required to write the differential equations

Comment: Where did you get the idea that you can pass additional parameters this way? Neither [matlabdoc: ode45](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html), [matlabdoc: odeset](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html) nor [matlabdoc: extra parameters in functions](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) has any hint that there is a corresponding mechanism.

Comment: @LutzL  Here, https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masfz/ModelingInfectiousDiseases/Chapter6/Program_6.1/Program_6_1.m   they have given these parameters as a single vector. If, given as a single vector is it possible? How can I give the randomly generated noise value into the differential equation as the noise term changes at each time step

Comment: Perhaps it is sufficient to create and pass the `options` object. Try it out. The `noise` parameter should then have its new (constant) value for every interval `[t, t+tstep]`.

Comment: That code uses an outdated way to pass parameters – it dates from ~15 years ago and has been deprecated since the introduction of [anonymous functions and closures](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html). The old code will still work if you pass an empty options object, but will run more slowly. I suggest updating it to use the modern method. Also, the integration method the code uses for what appears to be  a stochastic differential equation is highly dubious.